# Package manager, dpkg-query is not available

Tags: package-management, dpkg

Why does `dpkg -p packageName` for some package (example `adduser`, `dash`) display info thereof, but for other package like nodejs, git, firefox display `dpkg-query: package name is not available`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html) explains it ;-) `man dpkg-query`:

```
-p, --print-avail [package-name...]
       Display details about packages, as found in
       /var/lib/dpkg/available.  If no package-name is specified, it will
       display all package entries in the available database (since dpkg
       1.19.1).  When multiple package-name are listed, the requested
       available entries are separated by an empty line, with the same
       order as specified on the argument list.

       Users of APT-based frontends should use `apt show package-name`
       instead as the available file is only kept up-to-date when using
       dselect.
```

The last sentence explains it: use `apt show package-name`

Example:

```
$ apt show firefox
Package: firefox
Version: 87.0+build3-0ubuntu4
Priority: optional
Section: web
Origin: Ubuntu

$ apt show git
Package: git
Version: 1:2.30.2-1ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: vcs
Origin: Ubuntu
```

etc.